# JSONata Filter Array by starts-with criteria

Tags: json, jsonata

I'm pretty new to JSONata, and I need to write a query that will search/filter an array and return only the values that meet the criteria.
Specifically:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "externalIds": [
                "005262615581",
                "1395464646",
                "566955222",
                "6696630050055999",
                "99506533221233"
            ],
            "firstName": "Brian",
            "id": "a91f91af91af91a9f11fakeid",
            "lastName": "lastName",
            "office": null,
            "phone": null,
            "role": "Admin",
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried $Contains, and $Filter, but I honestly don't know the syntax to accomplish the "starts-with" concept.
I need to filter the "externalIds" array and only return the IDs that begin with 005, NOT contain 005.
So in this body I need it to return "005262615581".

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions and the [$match function](https://docs.jsonata.org/string-functions#match):

```
data.externalIds[$match($, /^005/)]
```

See it live on the playground: https://stedi.link/fa5C2GZ